# JavaScript, como organizar paneles de un Ext.Window?

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs

Estoy creando un Ext.Window y lo estoy intentando organizar con paneles, ya los he creado pero no comprendo bien como darles estructura, Quiero que un icono y dos frases se vean de la siguiente forma:

```
-------------------------------
|           |       Frase 1
|    Icono  | -----------------
|           |       Frase 2

-------------------------------
```

Y he usado el siguiente código:

```
var Panel1 = new Ext.Panel({
    header: false,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    collapsible: false,
    layout: 'column',
    items [{
          xtype: 'label',
          text: "Frase 1",
          style: 'font-size:12px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px'
          }]
});

var Panel2 = new Ext.Panel({
    header: false,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    collapsible: false,
    layout: 'column',
    items [{
          xtype: 'label',
          text: "Frase 2 2",
          style: 'font-size:12px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px'
          }]
});

var miIcono = Ext.create({
   xtype: 'box',
   height: 30,
   width: 30,
   autoEl: {
        tag: 'img',
        src: 'rutaDeMiImagen'
       }
});

myNewWindow = nex Ext.Window({
    width: 400,
    height: 250,
    items : [miIcono, Panel1, Panel2]
});

myNewWindow.show()
```

Pero se me muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
-------------
|   Icono   |
-------------
|  Frase 1  |
-------------
|  Frase 2  |
-------------
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: ¿Que versión de `Ext` estas usando?

Comment: Buenos Marcos, gracias por interesarte por mi pregunta, pues en mi caso mi Ext es el Ext 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`TableLayout`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.TableLayout).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {

  var Panel1 = new Ext.Panel({
    header: false,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    collapsible: false,
    html: "Frase 1",
    style: 'font-size:12px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px'
  });

  var Panel2 = new Ext.Panel({
    header: false,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    collapsible: false,
    layout: 'column',
    html: "Frase 2",
    style: 'font-size:12px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px'
  });

  var miIcono = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'box',
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    rowspan: 2, // ACA indicamos que ocupa 2 filas
    autoEl: {
      tag: 'img',
      src: 'rutaDeMiImagen'
    }
  });

  var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'table',
    layoutConfig: {
      columns: 2 // ACA indicamos que son 2 columnas
    },
    items: [
      miIcono,
      Panel1,
      Panel2
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Comment: He probado y curiosamente se muestran toda seguidas en vez de bajar, intentaré averiguar por qué pasa esto